# finding server IP on postgres heroku database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, coldfusion

I have a Heroku Postgres database. There are three slots to connect to a Heroku server:

- Server : ?
- Username : (I have it)
- Password : (I have it)

How do I find the server IP to connect to my Heroku DB?

Comment: ping it from a command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

From the output of a `heroku config` you will see an entry for `DATABASE_URL`, it takes the form of:

```
postgres://username:password@host:port/database_name
```

In your case you will want the value in the host just after the `@` symbol.

Answer (score -1):

You should not connect using the IP address, use a hostname instead. The hostname is in the connectionsstring. Heroku Dev Center has more details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress

If you really need the IP address, you can resolve the hostname to an address with a command like `nslookup`:

```
nslookup foo-domain.com
```